# Changing the section format

Tags: sectioning, formatting

Consider the `\section{abc}`

the output will be like

```
1. abc
```

how can I change the '.' to  '-' or vice versa. i.e.

```
2- abc
```

Comment: This is not necessarily true.  What class are you using?  A naive hack for the `article` class would be `\makeatletter\renewcommand\thesection{\@arabic\c@section-}\makeatother` ... but look at what that does to the Table of Contents (or if you also have subsections).  It is therefore best to provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: I think the package [titlesec](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) can be of help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Redefining `\thesection` doesn't help, because this will give wrong results when referencing a section number.

A “package free” solution is to access the `\@seccntformat` feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname\ --\ }
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}

We're in section~\ref{sec:intro}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}-}
```

for that specific purpose. Note that you could also use `roman`, `Roman`, `alph` or `Alph` instead of `arabic`, and you can also customize further by adding `\thechapter`, for instance.

Comment: Unfortunately this is wrong. References to sections will contain the dash, which is certainly unwanted.

Answer (score 2):

Without an additional knowledge about usage it may be simply (see probably corrected spacing):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\thesection{\arabic{section}--\hspace{-1em}}
\begin{document}

\section{First}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try doing `\ref{sec:whatever}` when the label is linked to a section?

Comment: @egreg I know, that ALL should be labelled "Achtung! Minen!", but without the requested usage I choose such a solution.