# Add section symbol to section

Tags: sectioning, formatting, sections-paragraphs

I would like to know how can I add the section symbol `§`, so that it will be displayed as follows.

> > §4 First section

> > §5 Second section

By default, it is generated as follows when a `\section` command is used.

> > 4 First section

> > 5 Second section

**Edit:**

This is one solution:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\S\arabic{section}}
```

However, it adds `§` also with `\subsection` command. Is there another solution?

Comment: No, I don't. But I see you solve my problem. Question is replaced/duplicated. I use just \renewcommand{\thesection}{\S\arabic{section}}

Comment: Pay attention that it also adds the same symbol in `\subsection`s.

Comment: You can also see [Changing the section format](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119667/changing-the-section-format) for a package free version.

Comment: Note that § is the *section* sign, not the *paragraph* sign (the "pilcrow" ). See the Wikipedia articles for the Section Sign (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign) and the Paragraph Sign (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps the quickest way is to use the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\section*{An unnumbered test section}
\section{Another test section}
\subsection{Another test subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]